# JavaScript - AJAX wait for Return Value from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am newbie in AJAX. My goal is to open in JavaScript a php file.

```js
function checkCorrect(userEntry, solution) {
    return fetch("checkSolution.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: `userEntry=${userEntry}&solution=${solution}`,
    })
    
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((res) => (res))
    .catch(err => console.log("checkCorrect: " + err));
} 

function checkSolution() {
  result = checkCorrect(userEntry, solution);
  alert(result)
}
```

My problem is, alert() in checkSolution shows "**[object Promise]**"

and not the real value coming from php. In php there is just a

> echo "hi";

Thanks,
BM

Comment: I want to use vanilla javascript.   I am also open for any other approaches as well. At the end, I want to use result from PHP in javascript via a variable.

Comment: `checkCorrect(userEntry, solution).then(alert);`

Comment: Since `fetch()` makes the an asynchronous request to the server, it returns a promise and not the result. You can read more about fetch and how it works (with many examples) [in MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use **async** before the **function** declaration so JS knows this is an async function, also you need to use **await** to wait for the promise to resolve. Here is an example:

```js
function async checkCorrect(userEntry, solution) {
    try {
      const requestParams = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        body: `userEntry=${userEntry}&solution=${solution}`,
      }
      
      const result = await fetch("checkSolution.php", requestParams)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((res) => (res))
 
      return result;
    } catch(e) {
      handleYourError(e);
    }
} 

function checkSolution() {
  result = checkCorrect(userEntry, solution);
  alert(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mario for the fetch version of the code.  I adjusted your version little bit, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In fact **fetch** is asynchronous. I didn't know.
In my case I am looking for synchronous method.

**XMLHttpRequest** is the right approach in my case.

An here is the solution:

```js
function checkCorrect(userEntry, solution) {
    var ret_value = null;

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {           
            ret_value =  xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    
    xmlhttp.open("POST","checkSolution.php",false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("userEntry="+userEntry+"&solution="+solution);

    return ret_value;
}
```

The 3rd parameter of xmlhttp.open() is the important part:

if true = asynchronous, if false = synchronous

Thanks, BM

Comment: This is not a good solution. [As stated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open): _"Note: Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive to the user experience and should be avoided; **in fact, many browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely.** Synchronous requests are permitted in Workers"_. Why do you even need the request to be synchronous in the first place? Sure, it has it's use cases, but in most cases you don't need it and are used because people don't understand asynchronous programming.

Comment: Thank you M. Eriksson! you convinced me :-)  I reimplemented required parts of my code, I go will use asynchronous via of fetch() 